Does Arkit have trouble outdoors in bright light and with very large planes to detect?
We are using Unity and Arkit.  We are setting up an experience outdoors and using plane detection in bright light.  There is a very large plane in the scene and I am trying to set multiple anchors on that plane.  Arkit is having trouble placing anchors and when they are placed, there is at times, significant drift.  Should I be using a different type of anchor than plane anchors with the bright light.
